# JQuery Slider: Calling function without ID but with the object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-ui-slider

I'm implementing a Slider with JQuery and I have the following problem.

The function is called upon load and it generates a slider with the Id from the div-element:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#value" ).val(ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#value" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });

<div id="slider" >
```

I would rather have it called upon loading and pass the object -something like this:

```
function createSilder(object) {
        object.slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#value" ).val(ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#value" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
}

<div id="slider" onload="createSlider(this)">
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried your code?

There is probably no problem, it just depends on the way the plugin has been coded.

Just be careful to pass the jQuery object : `<div id="slider" onload="createSlider($(this));">`.

Comment: Yes Ive tried my code and unfortunately it doesnt work.. I tried yours and it doesnt work either

Comment: Why do you want to wait for the `div` loading? If you put your code `$("#slider").slider(...);` in the `jQuery.ready` handler (this is what you do with the `$(function() {..})`, you are sure that the DOM is ready and that your `div` is loaded?

Comment: actually it did work, <div> just doesnt accept the onload handler.. the solution was, i connected it with an image and added --onload="createSlider($(this.parentNode))"-- :  

<div id="slider">
  <img id="label" src="image.png" onload="createSlider($(this.parentNode))"/>
</div>

Comment: OK, yes I understand well. Great!